# Open a command prompt at a specific location followed by running a script at that location with some command line arguments using python

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

I was able to open command prompt and change the directory to required location using the subprocess module, but I was unable to pass further arguments to run an application along with some command line arguments. I am new to the subprocess module, so I did some search over stackoverflow couldn't find the desired result.

Mycode:

```
import subprocess
path = r"C:/Users/Application_Folder"
p = subprocess.Popen(r"cmd.exe", cwd="C:/Project_Files", shell=True)
```

**Desired output:**

```
Path: C:\Users\Application_folder\Application.exe
Need to open the cmd prompt in windows at the Application_folder location, 
run the Application.exe by passing some command line arguments, using python
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the command line you actually want to execute, with the executable path and whatever arguments you want to pass:

```
command_line = [r'C:\Users\Application_Folder\Application.exe', '/argument1', '/argument2']
p = subprocess.Popen(command_line, cwd=r'C:\Project_Files')
```

A couple of notes to keep in mind:

- You *shouldn't* use `shell=True`. It's not necessary here -- in fact it's almost never necessary -- but it does introduce a potential security risk.
- The whole point of raw string literals (starting with `r'` or `r"`) is to change how backslash characters within the string are interpreted. `r'C:\Program Files'` is exactly the same string as `"C:\\Program Files"`. If your string doesn't have backslashes in it, don't bother using the `r` prefix.